# Null Pointer in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When i am running my any application it gives this error in androdi studio. please help

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.getMinimumSize(BasicComboBoxUI.java:934)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.getPreferredSize(BasicComboBoxUI.java:911)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1661)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.FixedSizeButton.getPreferredSize(FixedSizeButton.java:89)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.FixedSizeButton.getMinimumSize(FixedSizeButton.java:80)
    at java.awt.FlowLayout.minimumLayoutSize(FlowLayout.java:463)
    at java.awt.Container.minimumSize(Container.java:1840)
    at java.awt.Container.getMinimumSize(Container.java:1825)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(JComponent.java:1745)
    at java.awt.BorderLayout.minimumLayoutSize(BorderLayout.java:653)
    at java.awt.Container.minimumSize(Container.java:1840)
    at java.awt.Container.getMinimumSize(Container.java:1825)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(JComponent.java:1745)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AvdComboBox.<init>(AvdComboBox.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.ExtendedDeviceChooserDialog$2.<init>(ExtendedDeviceChooserDialog.java:92)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.ExtendedDeviceChooserDialog.<init>(ExtendedDeviceChooserDialog.java:92)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.ManualTargetChooser.getTarget(ManualTargetChooser.java:54)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.editor.ShowChooserTarget.showPrompt(ShowChooserTarget.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.getState(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:267)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.ExecutionEnvironment.getState(ExecutionEnvironment.java:201)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:58)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunner.execute(GenericProgramRunner.java:31)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:53)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunner.execute(GenericProgramRunner.java:31)
    at com.intellij.execution.ProgramRunnerUtil.executeConfiguration(ProgramRunnerUtil.java:94)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.start(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:396)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.access$400(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:61)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$5.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:384)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:332)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:569)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: @jas do you know how to resolve this .........

Comment: @Jas The problem is with the IDE, not the code. Read the logs. `at com.android.tools.idea.` is the Android Studio package name.

Comment: Its happen on with every app . i think this problem with studio .

Comment: Yes, that is what the exception says. What version of Studio?

Comment: @cricket_007 will please tell me how to solve.

Comment: ReDownload Android Studio or use IntelliJ. There is nothing you can do to solve a problem with the IDE.

Comment: @cricket_007 studio version 1.5.1

Comment: Either that or you need to create or do something with the emulator AVD's since `AvdComboBox` is the last Android Studio related class that is accessed.

Comment: i am going to reinstall studio ......